# How can I add an existing tab of a windows form in another windows forms page?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Working on c# 2.0
.NET windows forms

I would like to show  existing tab of a windows form in another windows forms page referecing the page which has the tab I want to show.?

Comment: are these tabs in the same application ?

Comment: I don't believe that Windows Forms allows one Control (Button, Tab, Container, etc.) to appear in more than one place, so I'm not sure it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Create a User control which contains all the cotrols in the tab. Now u can use that user control in both forms. Another way is to create separate forms for each tab and use these forms in tabbed form as well as another windows forms u want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correct, but here's what I get:
You have a window form say FormA on which you have a Tab Control, the Tab Pages might contain some more controls like TextBoxes etc.
Now you want this TabControl with all its child controls to be MOVED to a new form say FormB, by MOVED I mean the very instance of the Tab Control on FormA rather than a new instance. Which will mean that if user had typed something on say a TextBox within the TabPage even the User's typed text should be present in FormB when the entire control is moved there.

If the above scenario is right, then as someone above pointed out this is NOT ALLOWED in .Net one control is hosted in one container it can not be visible at two places simulteneously.

However, you might be interested in showing(rather using) the control in another form just for a while and it is alright if I totally rip off the control from the first form. Say a scenario where FormA will open FormB as a modal window and pass on its own Tab Control to it, user will use the control on FormB then close the modal Form FormB and the Tab control is back in its original position.

This is quite possible, just remove the Tab Control from its container in FormA pass it to FormB which will add it to some container and display it and vice versa.

For eg. say on a button Click on FormA you can write:

```
        FormB myForm = new FormB();
        this.Controls.Remove(this.tabControl1);
        myForm.AddTabControlToPanel(this.tabControl1);
        myForm.Show();
```

then the FormB will have a function

```
    public void AddTabControlToPanel(TabControl tc)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Add(tc);
        tc.Left = 10;
        tc.Top = 10;
        tc.Width = 200;
        tc.Height = 200;
    }
```